# I have a question about the output in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

This is the code

```
$connect = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

if ($connect->connect_error) {
    die("Unable to Connect : " . connect_error);
}

$sql = "CREATE TABLE student(
    student_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(50),
    age INT,
    gender VARCHAR(20)
);";

if ($connect->query($sql) === true) {
    echo "New Tables has been Created <br><br>";
}
else {
    echo "There is an Error : " . $connect->error . "<br><br>";
}

echo "Connected Successfully!";
$connect -> close();
```

And this is the output

```
New Tables has been Created

Connected Successfully!
```

I just created a table and what I'm trying to ask is when I'm going to insert a data the output will print out like `New Data Inserted!` but without removing the `echo "New Tables has been Created <br><br>";` is that possible, is the `else if () {}` that is needed?

Comment: Just code the insert somewhere before the `close()`. This is a very odd question

Comment: Storing a student's age is going to get messy

Comment: Thanks for all who answered! You are all great help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very basic question, but still:

```
...
if ($connect->query($sql) === true) {
    echo "New Tables has been Created <br><be>";

    // put your insert code here

}
...
```